# Correct extraction of int from an edit window in WinAPI for logic testing

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an edit box which has attribute `ES_NUMBER` and on a button press am attempting to check if the value of the edit box is between 2 and 15 (inclusive).

Having checked on StackOverflow, I found the strong recommendation to use `strtol()` as opposed to `atoi()`, however neither have successfully allowed me to perform the necessary check. Please see below the current code.

```
char buff[1024];
GetWindowText(hWndNoOfTeams, (LPWSTR)buff, 1024);
int i;
i = strtol(buff,NULL,10);
    if ((i > 1)&&(i < 16)){
            MessageBox(hWnd, (LPCWSTR)buff, L"MSGBOX", MB_OK);
    }else{
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"The number of teams must be greater than 1 and less than 16.", L"MSGBOX", MB_OK);
    };
```

The test works correctly between 0 and 9, however, beyond that it always presents the second message box. I have a suspicion that the issue lies in the method of extraction of the integer from the string, as for all values the `buff` array contains the correct value.

Apologies if I have missed something that ought to be glaringly obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GetWindowText(hWndNoOfTeams, (LPWSTR)buff, 1024);
```

Never cast anything to `LPWSTR` or `LPSTR` or anything related to that. The compiler is telling you that `GetWindowText()` is expecting a wide character string, which is an array of `WCHAR`s, not an array of `char`s. The wide character APIs are loaded by default as all new Windows programs *should* be Unicode-aware.

There are separate conversion routines for wide strings, such as `wcstol()`.

Look up the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` macros and Unicode handling on Windows for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Unicode version of the Win32 API functions, so you need to use a Unicode character buffer and the Unicode version of strtol() to match:

```
WCHAR buff[1024] = {0};
GetWindowText(hWndNoOfTeams, buff, 1024);
int i = wcstol(buff, NULL, 10);
if ((i > 1) && (i < 16)) {
    MessageBox(hWnd, buff, L"MSGBOX", MB_OK);
} else {
    MessageBox(hWnd, L"The number of teams must be greater than 1 and less than 16.", L"MSGBOX", MB_OK);
};
```